# How do I use a Segue without losing data stored in the view that called it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm creating an application that uses modal segues. UIViewController 1 (which is a child of a UITabBarController) has a button that uses a modal segue to get to UIViewController 2 which also has a button to use a segue to get back to UIViewController 1. The problem is for some reason, when I get back to UIViewController 1, all the data is gone (i.e. Labels, and images are set back to their default values prior to any changes made while using the app)
Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes dont use segue to get back from UIViewController 2 to UIViewController 1.

Just paste this code to your UIViewController 2 button action

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Because you are using new segue for get back from UIViewController 2 to UIViewController 1 so it is creating a new instance of UIViewController 1. which is Not the Previous UIViewController 1 from where UIViewController 2 come.

I think you understand what i say

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, this works!! :D I think I get what you mean so basically this just un-does the segue, yeah? THANK YOU :)

Comment: Its ok if its work then aceept this answer.or you can upvote it